# Is it possible to have action potentials in cells lacking both dendrites and axons?

Tags: neuroscience

I'm reading Kandel. Chapter 3 states the following:

> Because the initial segment of the axon has the highest density of voltage-sensitive Na+ channels and therefore the lowest threshold for generating an action potential, an input signal spreading passively along the cell membrane is more likely to give rise to an action potential at the initial segment than at other sites in the cell.

I know it is possible to have dendritic spikes, which is an action potential given a much stronger input to open enough Na+ channels. But can there be a different action potential, not axonic nor dendritc, given that enough Na+ channels locally open in the cell membrane?

I've seen some papers talk about "somatic action potential", but its meaning and how it works I don't understand.

Comment: All of the action potentials you are describing involve the cell membrane. Do you mean to ask whether an action potential can occur in the soma? Are you thinking of an isolated soma with axons/dendrites removed? Does an action potential that starts somewhere else and spreads to the soma count? Are you asking for biological relevance or plausible theoretical possibility? What will the answer to this question teach you about neuroscience?

Comment: I am thinking about the theoretical possibility an action potential with axons/dendrites removed.

Comment: The soma of Dorsal root ganglion (DRG) neurons can fire action potentials.

Comment: There are many other electrically excitable cells other than neurons: muscles, pancreatic islet cells and even some plant cells.